# Down arrow on active tab without using images but only CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

Want to be able to on ACTIVE tab 
 1) Change the Background to RED and
 2) Have a down arrow under the tab not using images
As seen here [ https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs ] - but the given code does not have my second requirement (not to use images for a down arrow)

Comment: Have you tried something or you your request a code?

Answer (score 0):

This CSS class will make you give you an arrow-down image

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid __COLOR__;
}
```

You could put this as `position: absolute` inside the tab, then you will get your result

Read more at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Next time, just google it.

So, you need this html:

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

And this css:

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;  
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```